# What folders are in the solution of a project in C#?

Tags: c#, project-organization

I have started to work on application projects in C# (WPF.NET) and I would like to know the organizational standards of the projects.

I have seen that people use, folders like:

> Views/
>   ViewsModels/
>   Diccionaries/
>   Commands/
>   etc.

What folders should you have, for example, a point-of-sale application project? And an application of this in Xamarin?

Comment: Entirely up to you. *Some* project types contain some standard folders (and also, your title is odd, since *Solutions* contain *Projects*, not the other way around), but even there, they're usually only a *possible* convention. Find what works for you.

Comment: Up to you, you could have a folder called `Everything` and another called `EverythingElse` . however you search wpf folder structure in google, you should find many peoples opinions on how they structure a project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commonly used method is to name namespaces according to your folders. Although not everybody [likes](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/resharper-directory-name-donates-namespace-yes-or-no) it.

Since there exist naming conventions for namespaces, you could use that to extract your folder's name. So based on the naming conventions of the namespaces, you can extract the folder name.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) for the naming conventions.

Please note: your project already has a default namespace. You shouldn't use that in your folder structure; it the "root".

It follows this path:

> Company.(Product|Technology)[.Feature][.Subnamespace]

E.g., for your viewmodels:

```
mycomp.mysolution.web.viewmodels
```

and for something else:

```
mycomp.mysolution.web.somethingelse
```

Which results in a folder, called "somethingelse"

Comment: `A commonly used method is to name folders according namespaces.` It's sort of the other way around. You get automatically generated namespaces based on the folder structure of where you create the code file. I'm not aware of any way to prevent this automatic behavior in VS, and it'd be really annoying to manually have to change namespaces all the time.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your reply. I have another doubt in mind:

Are there some folders that always predominate in a project of my type? For example: Models

Comment: @Rigui73: hi, thanks is expressed by up-voting or marking as answer ;-) ... to answer your question: yes and no... it depends on your style... just don't create empty folders on forehand... that's really annoying.